# Recording streaming audio from a online radio

Tags: iphone

I am working on a application where I am playing a live radio from a url. I want to record the radio and save it to local file system.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

[iPhone Coding: Recording Audio](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/08/06/iphone-coding-recording-audio/)

You need to use `CFURLRef` to point to the file you want to record to. For example:

```
NSMutableString *fullpathname = @"/var/root/foo.amr";
CFURLRef url;
CFStringRef sref;

sref = CFStringCreateWithCString(nil, 
[fullpathname cStringUsingEncoding:
[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]],
kCFStringEncodingASCII);

url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, sref, 
kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
```

Start recording by initializing. Once you get this far, it's just a matter of bookkeeping to get your recorder started. Here's the relevant code. Allocate and initiate the recorder instance, activate it and assign it the `CFURLRef` URL you've created. Then tell it to start. Recording starts instantly.

```
// Start recording
recorder = [[AVRecorder alloc] init];
[recorder activate:self];
[recorder setFilePath:url];
[recorder start];
```

Stop the recording with "stop". When you're ready to finish recording, just send a stop message to your recorder and deactivate it. The file has already saved automatically to disk. If you want, you can query the number of bytes written before deactivating by sending a `recordedFileSizeInBytes` message.

```
[recorder stop];
[recorder deactivate];
```